# Which Linux distribution should I install?

Tags: dell, laptop, inspiron

My laptop is a 2017 Dell Inspiron Pentium 4415u@2.30GHz 64-bit with touchscreen.
I'm not sure which distribution will support this laptop. I would like to delve into Linux, so any suggestions would we appreciated!

Comment: Ubuntu is not a drop-in replacement for Windows. It's quite different. Folks who are successful with Ubuntu have two characteristics: 1) They are open to learning the differences, and 2) They are willing to do a bit of their own research when they have questions.

Comment: If you are coming from Windows I think that Kubuntu 20.04 is a great starting point.

Comment: All of the [official flavors](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) of Ubuntu desktop have a "Try Ubuntu" option when you boot from installation media.  This lets you test drive without affecting your current installation. From Windows, start here: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

The question is not about distributions. Whatever will support your laptop is going to be the Linux Kernel, not the Linux distribution. I'll recommend you Ubuntu 20.04. Ubuntu is very beginner friendly, and 20.04 is the latest LTS (Long Term Support) stable release, so you will find good support in the community and solid stability.